# if statements with multiple conditions in r?

Tags: r

[sample of data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOUnf.png)

Hi there,

Im trying to get the correct column to = 1 if 'stim_type' = 8 and 'response' = 35, and if 'stim_type' = 7 and 'response' = 34. Any other combination then correct = 0

Please let me know if that wasn't clear, any help is appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: `dat$new <- with(dat, +(stim_type == 8 & response == 35) | (stim_type == 7 & response == 34))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with `dplyr`:

`library(dplyr)`

```
df %>% 
  mutate(correct = ifelse((stim_type == 8 & response == 35) | (stim_type == 7 & response == 34), 1, 0))
```

Here is a solution with `base R`

```
df$correct <- ifelse((df$stim_type == 8 & df$response == 35) | (df$stim_type == 7 & df$response == 34), 1, 0)
```

In both cases, you're saying "if (`stim_type` = 8 AND `response` = 35) OR (`stim_type` = 7 AND `response` = 34), change the value of `correct` to 1, otherwise, keep it at zero."

Data:

```
structure(list(stim_type = c(8, 7, 7, 8, 7, 8, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 
7, 8), response = c(35, 35, 34, 35, 34, 35, 34, 34, 35, 35, 35, 
34, 35), correct = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-13L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to google `r if statement logical operators` you should have your answers but here is a small preview `if('stim_type' = 8 & 'response' = 35)` some explanation can be found here https://www.tutorialgateway.org/logical-operators-in-r/